# Angular 4 Dynamic form group

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a dynamic form group, im trying to achieve this

[image]

on add more click add 2 dynamic fields
im calling this function:

```
onAddSurgeries(){
    const control = new FormGroup({
        'surgery': new FormControl(null),
        'illness': new FormControl(null)
    });
      (<FormArray>this.form.get('surgeries')).push(control);
}
```

and this is how my html looks like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ctrl of form.get('surgeries')['controls']; let i = index">
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="ctrl['controls'].surgery"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="ctrl['controls'].illness"></td>
</tr>
```

I know the mistake I am doing, formControlName shouldn't be "`ctrl['controls'].surgery`" I am supposed to put "i" as `formcontrolname` when i have only one `formcontrol` instead of 2 controls in a `formgroup`, but in this case i don't know what should i enter in the formControlName
because when i submit the form the values of both inputs are empty because it is not synced with the formgroup controls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing (at least from question) the marking of the `formArrayName`. Also you are pushing formgroups to your formarray, which in template need to be marked with the index value in your iteration. Then your `formControlName`s are just the names you have specified, i.e `surgery` and `illness`:

```html
<table>
  <ng-container formArrayName="surgeries">
    <tr *ngFor="let ctrl of form.get('surgeries')['controls']; let i = index" 
      [formGroupName]="i">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="surgery"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="illness"></td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwhpcr?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: i knew i was missing something, thank you so much for pointing out :) it worked